# What is the difference between the Internet of Things and the Internet of Everything?

Tags: definitions

As the title says: What is the difference between the Internet of Things and the Internet of Everything and should I care?

I came cross two concepts the *Internet of* **Things** and the *Internet of* **Everything**. Can anyone help me understand: How do the two topics differ from each other?

If you have time to watch a 20 minute video, this is where I first got the topic from: [Introduction to the Internet of Everything by Eli the Computer Guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iCzQNTL4-Rs).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The *Internet of Everything* is primarily a marketing term [used by Cisco](https://newsroom.cisco.com/ioe), in contrast to the *Internet of Things* which is a more generic term used by many groups and manufacturers. Since IoE is used almost exclusively by Cisco, their definition should be quite reliable:

> The Internet of Everything (IoE) brings together people, process, data, and things to make networked connections more relevant and valuable than ever before-turning information into actions that create new capabilities, richer experiences, and unprecedented economic opportunity for businesses, individuals, and countries.

In practical terms, this boils down to a few key points, which I'll outline below.

### Machine to Machine (M2M) vs Machine to People (M2P)

The Internet of Things is primarily associated with connecting **machines** and **devices** together so they can share data, e.g. connecting your light bulb to your smartphone so you can control it.

The Internet of **Everything** is a more holistic term that considers every step of the process: human interaction with the computer; the machine to machine interaction; the output to the human and the process in general.

IoE can be used in industry to describe the changes that come about as a consequence of interconnected devices, and talk about the new processes that factories can use to be more efficient.

### The Scale of the Internet of Everything

The IoE can also encompass systems bigger than you traditionally find in IoT networks. One example on the Cisco website is a train network, which is far bigger than you'd find in a domestic IoT network (the train could have a whole IoT network of its own, then be connected to a **bigger** network!).

Overall, there isn't a lot of difference - it's just a marketing buzzword used by Cisco, but it's otherwise very similar to the term *Internet of Things*.

Answer (score 8):

What [Internet of Everything](http://internetofeverything.cisco.com/sites/default/files/docs/en/ioe-value-index_Whitepaper.pdf)'s aim is:

> connecting the unconnected  — people-to-people (P2P),
>   machine-to-people (M2P), and machine-to-machine  (M2M) — via the
>   Internet of Everything (IoE).

So basically it seems to be a broader term, the next generation of IoT [according to Cisco](http://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en_us/about/ac79/docs/innov/IoE_Economy.pdf).

**The point is that all devices will have direct connection to the Internet**, while in IoT the devices are members of an Internet-Like-Network but not necessarily the Internet itself.

[What makes it possible](http://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en_us/about/ac79/docs/innov/IoE_Economy.pdf) is the IPv6 which will allow countless devices to have its own IP address.

> Second, barriers to connectedness continue to drop. For example, IPv6
>   overcomes  the  IPv4   limit   by  allowing  for 
>   **340,282,366,920,938,463,463,374,607,431,768,211,456**  more     people,
>   processes, data, and things to be connected to the Internet.
>   Amazingly, IPv6  creates enough address capacity for every star in the
>   known universe to have 4.8  trillion addresses.

So IoE emphasizes TCP/IP connection and larger, more comprehensive networks.

But all in all there are not much differences at all. Using only TCP/IP in IoE exclude a lot of IoT platforms and devices but the concept does not change much.

Also the targeted connection of M2M, P2P, M2P does not make a significant difference either.